# Compiler encountered an internal error (Error code 2) Vulkan/MacOS/MoltenVK?

Tags: macos, vulkan, moltenvk

On a call to `vkCreateGraphicsPipelines` I'm getting the following output from the MoltenVK library:

```
[mvk-error] VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED: Render pipeline compile failed (Error code 2):
Compiler encountered an internal error.
```

and then `vkCreateGraphicsPipelines` returns `VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED`.

This only occurs on one of my two Macs.  On the other Mac, and on Windows and Linux machines, the program works fine.

Any ideas for next steps in debugging or reporting this?  Anyone know what "Error code 2" means, or how to get more information about the internal compiler error?  Anyway to turn on extra debug / logging in MoltenVK?

Comment: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/MoltenVK/issues/1183

Comment: Could you try turning on Metal API Validation in the scheme settings in XCode? If it's a Metal error bubbling up rather than an error internal to MoltenVK then you might get lucky and get some information printed to the debug out.

Comment: @Columbo: I turned Metal API Validation on by setting enviornment variable `METAL_DEVICE_WRAPPER_TYPE` to `1`, and apart from the message that Metal Validation was on, it presented no additional output.